# Проблема с получением данных из firebase, ошибка при конветре типов данных

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase

```
ошибка: "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to
type com.example.mytreningwork.model.ModelLoadTrainingExec"
```

На скрине код , где возникает ошибка

[image: Ошибка Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.mytreningwork.model.ModelLoadTrainingExec]

```
    DB.child("${mAuth.currentUser?.uid.toString()}/CUSTOM_TRAINING/$nameTraining")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    val list = snapshot.children.map{it.getValue(ModelLoadTrainingExec::class.java)?:ModelLoadTrainingExec()}
//                    view.RecyclerViewDisplayTrainingExec.apply {
//                        adapter = ViewExecTrainigAdapter(list)
//                    }
                }
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
            })
```

На фото ниже структура ноды firebase , от куда берутся данные

[image: Структура ноды firebase]

Код модели(дата класса)

```
data class ModelLoadTrainingExec(
var execCount : String  = "0",
var execName : String = "none",
var execTask : String = "0",
var execTime : String = "0"
)
```

Comment: 1.Код в виде текста 2. Я нигде не нашел свойства children для DataSnapshot

Comment: Можешь по подробнее написать, непонятно.